# Generate static library by namespace in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, static, split, namespaces

I have a Visual Studio solution 'Libs'.  In this solution I have a separate folders:

'Threads', 'Strings'. For example in folder Threads I have Threads.cpp and Mutex.cpp in this file I have class namespace libs::threads and in this namespace I have class and method.

It is possible to generate static library which consist only libs from namespace libs::threads or libs::strings without split folders to new solutions ? (Like in Boost).

Comment: "solution" is probably a term used by some [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) that you're using.  And you're asking if this IDE you've chosen has this build option, yes?

Comment: Yes solution is term from Visual Studio C++. Because main idea is that i have one solution ( or project - depends on the IDE ) and separate folders with libraries. But I think that i can use some other IDE or Makefile or Cmake ...